# Confused about the differences between NET and RAM on the EOS network

Tags: ram, mainnet, resources, net, network

I'm trying to wrap my head around the differences between the 2 resources on the EOS network: NET and RAM.

My understanding is that "NET" represents the share of the entire EOS blockchain that we are entitled to use to store "data" in a "transient" manner based on the amount of EOS tokens we've staked (i.e. the more EOS tokens we stake, the more network capacity we are allowed to use) whereas "RAM" is a scarce resource dedicated to storing data of our account in a "persistent" manner.

Based upon the above understanding, I'm a bit confused about the following points:

1. What are the differences between the types of data to be stored on
   "NET" and "RAM"?
2. If the data stored on "NET" is transient in nature, where will the
   data go after it's "gone" (i.e. after the "NET" capacity is
   "regenerated") ?
3. Where exactly are those pieces of data for NET and RAM stored?

I would appreciate it if you could help me clarify on the above points.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In the EOSIO ecosystem, the CPU, RAM, and NET are all provided to the chain by the block producers.

The EOS tokens gives you access to the staking resources (CPU & NET = Bandwidth) which are replenished after an amount of time and then there is RAM (on-chain storage). Keep in mind that developers have to purchase enough RAM to run a smart contract.

RAM is for actions that require storing something in memory on the network such as accounts. RAM can be consumed for different things such as airgrabs, moving airdropped tokens for the very first time, and etc.

RAM is only for state storage (e.g token balances) so you only need it if your smart contract stores state to the database. If you need to read data from the transaction log, stake NET. Remember that staking EOS doesn't play a role in RAM.

All in one, one has to stake NET for the transaction data and stake CPU for the time it takes to execute the transaction. Again staking renews given enough time, unlike RAM.

EOSIO = Software, EOS = token on the Main Net

Answer (score 1):

BPs have hardware limit RAM (random access memory) and hardware limit receive packages from network.
RAM is about how many data need to save each BPs about your account.
NET is about how many people send transactions now.

Comment: NET is also about the bandwidth usage and data (size) that has been transferred, not just the count of transactions.